# MS Query with comma separated parameters

Tags: sql, excel, ms-query

How to make MS Query work with comma separated parameters in Excel cell?

My query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM ABC
WHERE Id in (?)
```

When I put id number for example "1" the query works, but I want to put into a parameters cell a few id's 1, 2, 3, 4 etc, but then I'm trying to to this the query doesn't work... How can I put parameter with comma separated values?

Comment: [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ac1aff14-9f59-4cd5-a993-9c0519dca774/query-parameter-with-comma-separated-numeric-values?forum=accessdev) may help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` in you sql query.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (1,2,3,4);
```

also try to use `BETWEEN` with comma as parameters.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Comment: But I want it to be in parameter not in query.

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 diff way to do it:

```
select * from abc where id in ('1','2','3') etc but not in excel - maybe use notepad++
```

second way :)

```
select * from abc where (id like '1' or id like '2' or id like '3') etc
```

:)

Comment: But I want it to be in parameter not in query.